# Does a positron go into decay process like some other elementary particles ? Electron, it's counterpart is stable and has a long half life

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, antimatter, stability, elementary-particles

Can a positron decay? Or is it a stable particle like its counterpart the electron?

(Reference: https://physics.aps.org/articles/v8/s138)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Are proton, antiproton, electron, positron the only observed subatomic particles that can freely exist and don't decay, i.e. are stable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/are-proton-antiproton-electron-positron-the-only-observed-subatomic-particles?rq=1)

Comment: @Jonas No information for positron !!!

Comment: There is. The positron is mentioned in the tite aswell as the question body which states that the positron is stable.

Answer (score 1):

The positron is stable, as the [antiparticle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/antimatter.html) of a stable particle, it has to be stable. It can disappear by annihilating on an electron, so that just energy remains,  but it can not decay. See also the [positronium,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) an unstable system of an electron bound to a positron.